# Using \label and \pageref with formatted page numbers seamlessly

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing, labels

I have a complicated document (book, really) with multiple formats for page numbers based on different divisions of the book (roman, arabic, and then things like 1*, [1], and <<1>>).  Each numbered section restarts at 1 and is differentiated by this formatting.

The goal is to be able to issue a command `\label{item}` and have a later `\pageref{item}` provide the formatted page number.  These references can be across divisions, so I need to get a reference like 3* in the section with pages numbered e.g. [7].

I have previously asked two complicated questions about indexing that have yielded a solution.  However, they break my scheme to make this referencing work.

I had issued the command

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}*}
```

for example, at the start of each section.  That both controlled formatting the page number in the document and making `\label` and `\pageref` do what I want, but didn't work with `\index` as makdindex refuses to allow non-numeric page numbers - writing [1] directly broke things.

I can easily fix the page number in the footer using fancyhdr.

How can I make `\label` write a formatted page reference so that `\pageref` can pull it out without my having to know what section the referenced item came from?

What follows is an MWE that doesn't work.  For page references to the name 'item', I'd like to get `\pageref` to return 1*.  For the page references to 'this', I'd like `\pageref` to return [1].

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,latin]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage*}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
This is an item.\label{item}
\newpage
You can read about {\itshape item\/} here: \pageref{item}.
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\fancyfoot[C]{[\thepage]}
You've read about {\itshape item\/} here: \pageref{item}.  But you should also read about this.\label{this}
\newpage
Have you read about {\itshape this\/} here: \pageref{this}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please extend your document to contain also the index stuff. Otherwise it is difficult to propose a solution to this problem that will also work with your other requirements. The best solution is maybe not another patch on top of the other, but some integrated approach.

Comment: That's really impossible.  The index stuff is in a function within a function that is only called by a package called gregorio tex that typesets Gregorian chant, and so then needs additional files of pieces of music to be read in so that the function gets triggered.  I'm willing to try anything and see if it works; but I can't really make anything like a minimal example out of what I'm currently doing.

I can note that to create the multiple indices, I use the imakeidx package, which redefines \index.

Comment: \label uses the page of the last \refstepcounter.  You can create a new counter and add \refstepcounter before \label.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid I don't understand.  The value of the page counter is the right page number,  as a pure integer, but I need it to be written by \label in the format [1] or 1* or <<1>> as appropriate to the division of the document for later recollection by \pageref.  That is, in the MWE, the page reference commands yield the right digit - they just aren't formatted properly.  Not sure how swapping to a new counter solves this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a simple redefinition of \label does the trick.  I do this at the beginning of each new division of the document where the page number format changes.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,latin]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage*}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\@bsphack \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{\@currentlabel }{\thepage* }}}\@esphack} 
\makeatother

This is an item.\label{item}
\newpage
You can read about {\itshape item\/} here: \pageref{item}.
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\fancyfoot[C]{[\thepage]}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\label}[1]{\@bsphack \protected@write \@auxout {}{\string \newlabel {#1}{{\@currentlabel }{[\thepage] }}}\@esphack} 
\makeatother
You've read about {\itshape item\/} here: \pageref{item}.  But you should also read about this.\label{this}
\newpage
Have you read about {\itshape this\/} here: \pageref{this}.

\end{document}
```